# cannot validate registration plugin with custom field

Tags: javascript, facebook, validation, plugins, registration

I'm trying to create a custom validation on the Facebook registration plugin fields.
But as soon as I add a custom field, the form just never be posted and the validate function is never called. Here is a simplified piece of code where address is the custom field :

```
<fb:registration 
  redirect-uri="https://socialike.eu/clientsiframes/essentiel/form/" 
  onvalidate="validate" 
  fields="[
    {'name':'name'},
        {'name':'email'},
        {'name':'address','description':'Address','type':'text'},
        {'name':'location'}
   ]">
</fb:registration>

<script>
    function validate(form){
        var errors={};
            errors.address = "ERROR";
        return errors;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I get "$_REQUEST is empty" and "Invalid 'client_id'." error when going to that page.  I see nothing but that.

Comment: My bad, the app was still in sandbox mode. Now you should be able access it. for the empty signed request it's normal since noting have been posted yet.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out why it was not working. Even if my app was only integrated in facebook application tab I had to set the "Website url" field in the application settings. Now the validate function is properly called.